# How to make my solver do backtracking (javascript)

Tags: javascript, sudoku, backtracking

Im in one of my last staps in my project, but I cant find the answer! 
I have a small sudoku solver. However, I cant make it work when it needs to do some backtracking. I need some help with that.

My code has some dutch names, so let me explain that:

```
zoekNul() = findZero()
vierkant = square
CheckRK()= Check row column 
Vulin() = Fillin()
```

The code tries 1 to 4 (if square is 4x4) and then fills the correct number.

```
  [1, 0, 3, 4], 
  [2, 0, 4, 1],
  [3, 4, 0, 2],
  [4, 1, 2, 3]
```

That would work, because it doesn't have to do backtracking

This wont, because it has to do backtracking:

```
[1, 0, 3, 4],
[2, 0, 4, 1],
[3, 0, 0, 2],
[4, 0, 2, 3]
```

this is my code:

```
var sq = [
    [1, 0, 3, 4],
    [2, 0, 4, 1],
    [3, 4, 0, 2],
    [4, 1, 2, 3]
];
var x;
var y;
var nMax = 4;

function zoekNul(vierkant) {
    for (var i = 0; i < nMax; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < nMax; j++) {
            if (vierkant[i][j] === 0) {
                x = i;
                y = j;
                return [x, y];
            }
        }
    }
    return [-1, -1];
}

function vulin(vierkant) {

    if (zoekNul(vierkant)[0] == -1) {

        alert(vierkant);
    } else {
        for (var w = 1; w < nMax + 1; w++) {
            if (checkRK(vierkant, x, y, w) === true) {
                vierkant[x][y] = w;
                vulin(vierkant);



            } 
        }
    }

}




function checkRK(vierkant, x, y, w) {
    var bool = true;
    for (var k = 0; k < nMax && bool; k++) {
        if (vierkant[x][k] == w || vierkant[k][y] == w) {
            bool = false;
            break;
        }

    }
    return bool;
}


console.log(vulin(sq));
```

Please note, im quite new to programming. I wrote the code with some help from my teacher.

Thanks in advance

PS: a jsfiddle link can be found here:
http://jsfiddle.net/45fuW/

Comment: Where did you try to do the backtracking?

Comment: I would think in my vulin() function. But I have no clue how I could do this. My teacher said this, under vulin(vierkant); in my vulin() function add this: vierkant[x][y] = 0; . This doesn't work so now Im out of ideas.

Comment: 2nd square does not require BT. You fill in this order: 1st row, 2nd row, 3rd column, 3rd row, 4th row

Comment: But if it first enters a 1 because it fits, but at the end the complete filled in sudoku is invalid, it needs to return and change the 1 for example. I don't think your idea wont work